# Anaconda reports name 'dateutil' is not defined but python-dateutil is installed

Tags: anaconda, python-dateutil

I am very new to Python and working my way through a Jupyter tutorial at https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/jupyter-notebooks#introduction

When I run the code, the line `parseddate = dateutil.parser.parse(row[1])` gives an error `name 'dateutil' is not defined`

I'm doing all this in Anaconda, and I checked that the python-dateutil package is installed and it is, version 2.8.1

I'm not sure how to proceed, beyond checking that the package is present.

Thanks

Comment: You need to import the package. ‘import dateutil’

Comment: Thank you. I had imported datetime but not dateutil.